# Grub doesn't always launch at Boot

Tags: grub2

I installed Xubuntu on an old HP Pavillion laptop. I've a problem with Grub. Sometimes, instead of booting, the laptop remains stuck on the HP screen with the various function key options at the bottom.
If I press F9 and choose to boot from the hard disk it boots normally.

What's the cause of this issue and how to work around it?

Comment: Your disk isn't spinning up quite fast enough.  I've seen it, but it's exceptionally rare.

Comment: When there was Windows on this machine, it used to boot normally. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Check BIOS settings.  The only time I ever had the problem, there was an option on how fast to spin up hard drives in BIOS,  I think it was called hard disk pre-delay or something like that.  So, you could delay spinning up the HD if the video card took a lot of juice right when it fired up.  reference https://archive.techarp.com/showFreeBOG3ac9.html?lang=0&bogno=271

Comment: There's no such setting in the BIOS on this machine I'm afraid.